# Question about $\pi_0(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm studying the fundamental group of a topological space and I've studied a proof checking that $\pi_1(X)$ is a group.

I'm thinking if the space of path components $\pi_0(X)$ is a group or not. I've tried to proof it is but don't see the way, so I suspect it isn't a group. Could anyone provide me a counterexample of this fact? (or tell me where could I found a proof in case it is).

The operation $*$ is the usual composition of pahts.

Thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: It is just a non-empty set and as every non-empty set it can be equipped we a multiplication that makes it a group. However I don't see any 'natural' ways to do that. Wich one of the components must serve as identity?.. And why?

Comment: @drhab Sorry, I forgot telling that the multiplication is the usual path composition

Comment: I don't understand. By path composition two paths are composed to become one path. A multiplication on paths. However, here we are dealing not with paths but with path components. What should come out if two pathcomponents are composed/multiplicated? I think that $\pi_0$ should be looked at as a functor from **Top** to **Set** (not to **Grp** or to **Ab**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ is a pointed set. It does not have a natural group structure. However, if $X$ is a topological group, then $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ (where $x_0$ is the identity) inherits a natural group structure. Let $C(x)$ be the path component of $x \in X$. Then $C(x) * C(y) = C(x * y)$ is a well-defined operation on $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ that gives a group structure, with $C(x_0)$ being the identity. Try to prove this!

As for your question, since $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ is a set of path components, it cannot be given a group structure via path composition. How can you use path composition to "compose" two path components?

Comment: What does it mean that  $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ "does not have a natural group structure" and how do you prove that?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg If $X$ is just a discrete space, any group structure on $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ is equally valid. There is no natural choice. This is an example of what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Dear Ayman, I know very well that $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ has no natural group structure. What I mean is that one should prove that there is  no functor from pointed spaces to groups which composed with the forgetful functor from groups to sets yields $\pi_0$. This should be easy to prove but I haven't checked it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. @GeorgesElencwajg I continue without seeing why in general $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ has no natural group structure, could you give an example, please? Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Anthony,  Ayman gave a perfect answer in his comment above: any non-empty set would then have a natural group structure obtained by endowing that set with the discrete' topology.